# Generate every row total of a table input tag in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

[this type output i want i am fetchint data from database and storing in table than quantity will be adde by usernow on if user enter uantity than i want total in add column`
                
                    Sr. No. 
                    Product Name
                    Price
                    Quantity
                    ADD

```
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <?php
            mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'"); 
              $query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $statement LIMIT $startpoint,$limit");
              while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
              {


            ?>
                <td><?php echo $row['srno'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['pname'];?></td>


               <!-- <td><input id="price" type="number" value="0" oninput="updateOutput()"/></td>
                <td><input id="qty" type="number" value="0" oninput="updateOutput()" /></td>-->
               <td> <input id="price" type="number" value="<?php echo $row['price'];?>" oninput="myFunction()"></td>
               <td><input id="qty" type="number"  value="0" oninput="myFunction2()" ></td>
                <td>

               <p id="demo">0</p>

                </td>


            </tr>
```

`][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x28P9.png)

Comment: are u looking for `quantity*price` ??

Comment: yes i want to generate total

Comment: when i use the quantity option price will change in total? want to use jQuery?

Comment: yes i tried jQuery but it work only first row

Comment: plz share the code which u tried... i think u are using same id for all, just share the code

Comment: check out this code

Comment: u are using same id for all fields id must be unique

Comment: are u telling about input tag id?

Comment: check the answer u will get the idea,

Comment: ok i m tring your ans

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript Solution:**

```js
function getResult(){
    var price       = document.getElementsByClassName('price');
    var quantity    = document.getElementsByClassName('quantity');
    var totalPrice=0,totalQuantity=0;

    for(var i=0;i<price.length;i++){
        totalPrice+=parseInt(price[i].value);
    }

    for(var i=0;i<quantity.length;i++){
        totalQuantity+=parseInt(quantity[i].value);
    }

    document.getElementById('totalPrice').innerHTML = totalPrice;
    document.getElementById('totalQuantity').innerHTML = totalQuantity;
  }

getResult();
```

```html
<table border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="product-table" >
    <tr style="background:#3cf;color:white">
        <th class="table-header-repeat line-left minwidth-1"><a href="">Price</a></th>
        <th class="table-header-repeat line-left minwidth-1"><a href="">Quantity</a></th>
        <th class="table-header-repeat line-left minwidth-1"><a href="">ADD</a></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><input class="price" onkeyup="getResult()" oninput="getResult()" type="number"  value="20"></td>
       <td><input class="quantity" onkeyup="getResult()" oninput="getResult()" type="number"  value="10"></td>
       <td><p id="demo">0</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><input class="price" onkeyup="getResult()" oninput="getResult()" type="number"  value="20"></td>
       <td><input class="quantity" onkeyup="getResult()" oninput="getResult()" type="number"  value="20"></td>
       <td><p id="demo">0</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><input class="price" onkeyup="getResult()" oninput="getResult()" type="number"  value="50"></td>
       <td><input class="quantity" onkeyup="getResult()" oninput="getResult()" type="number"  value="30"></td>
       <td><p id="demo">0</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background:black;color:white">
        <td id="totalPrice"></td>
        <td id="totalQuantity"></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: here quantity will be added by user

Comment: So, You can make above JavaScript Code as a `function`, Then you can see result by Calling Function @ParmarShyamsingh

Comment: how i can print total

Comment: Add and ID Example `<div id="priceResult"></div>` and set `document.getElementById('priceResult').innerHTML = totalPrice;` @ParmarShyamsingh

Comment: can u explain with example bcz i had put for loop in print rows

Comment: I updated the answer, Do you want like this? @ParmarShyamsingh

Comment: But It is working in my browser, Last row is for result. You can change quantity to show result. @ParmarShyamsingh

Comment: Before check reload the page. :)

Comment: no bro thanks but i want total in add column of each rows

Comment: and this input tag will be print as product item

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var price       = document.getElementsByClassName('price');
    var quantity    = document.getElementsByClassName('quantity');
    var totalPrice=0,totalQuantity=0;

    for(var i=0;i<price.length;i++){
        totalPrice+=parseInt(price[i].innerHTML);
    }

    for(var i=0;i<quantity.length;i++){
        totalQuantity+=parseInt(quantity[i].value);
    }

    console.log(totalPrice,totalQuantity); /*Here is your Result variable*/
 
 document.getElementById('priceResult').innerHTML = totalPrice; 
}
</script>
```

```html
<table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="product-table" >
    <tr>
                 
     
                    <th class="table-header-repeat line-left minwidth-1"><a href="">Price</a></th>
                    <th class="table-header-repeat line-left minwidth-1"><a href="">Quantity</a></th>
                    <th class="table-header-repeat line-left minwidth-1"><a href="">ADD</a></th>
                       
    </tr>
    <tr><?php
    mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'"); 
      $query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product");
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
      {
      ?>
                
                    
                   <td class="price" >5</td>
                   <td><input class="quantity" type="number"  value="0" oninput="myFunction()" ></td>
                    <td>
                     
                   <div id="priceResult"></div>

     </td>
                 
                                       
                </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: did u check this @ sumon sarker

Comment: You can't run PHP code in this code snipped. That's why error in result. Remove this answer. I updated the answer.